# NamedParameterJDBCTemplate and function syntax on different RDBMSs

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I need to support both, Oracle und SQL Server. I have pretty identical procedures named `get_current_date` in both DBs. Now I have a query:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE colDate < get_current_date()
```

This works beautifully in Oracle but lacks the `dbo.` prefix when executed in SQL Server.

Should Spring be able to handle that? What other options do I have? I dont think it should be necessary to determine the DB type myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Every JDBC driver should support the JDBC function escapes (defined in section 13.4.1 and listed in appendix D of the [JDBC 4.1 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/index.html)). For the `CURRENT_DATE` it is `CURRENT_DATE` or `CURRENT_DATE()`.

You can call this in a query as

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE colDate < {fn CURRENT_DATE}
```

You can query the list of supported functions of your specific driver with [`DatabaseMetaData.getTimeDateFunctions()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTimeDateFunctions%28%29)

BTW: This assumes you just want the current date of the database. It is not a general solution for calling user defined functions in your query.

Comment: Awesome! I knew something like this would exist. Thanks. Does this work for custom procedures as well?

Comment: No, the function escapes are an abstraction layer over common database functions that occasionally have (slightly) different implementations across databases. A JDBC driver should only implement the functions listed in appendix D of the spec. It is not a solution to call user defined functions (I also added that to my answer).

Comment: This totally works. Thanks again. But I still need an idea for custom procedures. If you can provide one, I can accept this post as the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Should Spring be able to handle that?

--> `get_current_date()` is database method/procedure (may it be of database or your custom) so it is dependent on database, Spring would not take care of that.

> What other options do I have?

--> Well you can put current date in query in code so it will be independent of database what you use. Something like :

```
String sql = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE colDate < " + new Date();
```

Comment: `get_current_date` is my own procedure in both DBs which serves as a wrapper for the system specific functions. I can't put the date in where I fire the query as we have elected the DBMS to serve the dates. (DB and Application run on different machines and we do not want to risk time setting differences to cause issues.)

Answer (score 0):

How about get current date in java something like:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
currentDate = cal.getTime();

and then you do:

SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE colDate < currentDate
```

Comment: As I wrote above: I can't put the date in where I fire the query in Java as we have elected the DBMS to be the one and only source for the current timestamp. If it's not possible we might have to rethink that.